# How do I override __type__ method in python object?

Tags: python

I create a Python class for some mathematical calculations. In that object, I am trying to change type(**type**) methods result. And my attempts failed.

When I try type() method for my object that appears
`<class '__main__.MyClassName'>`
I override type method in my method :

```py
class MyMathOBJ():
.   
.
.
    def __type__(self):
        return "MyMathOBJ"
```

But when I do that nothing changed. The same result. I was expecting just that result `MyMathOBJ`.

Comment: you cannot override this, `type` should return the *type object*, i.e. the class object, to begin with, so even if this were possible, returning a string would be a broken implementation. this sounds like an x-y problem, what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to change that `<class '__main__.MyClassName'>` result . With `MyMathOBJ`. For instance `a = 5;print(type(a))` code will print `int` . Just that . Not with confusing staff. I just want it.

Comment: Just it has better looking :) Aesthetic and Curiosity

Comment: I'd be interested to see if you can actually fake the result of `type`; not necessarily changing it to a str, but changing it at all.

Comment: @flakes what do you mean by "fake" it? You can, if you'd likey, dynamically set the `__class__` of an instance to any arbitrary class (python is very much open to metaprogramming and introspection). I'm not sure i'd recommend that unless you really know what you are doing. If you just want to change how the class object is *represented* when you print it, you just need to create a custom metaclass (i.e. a custom type)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hmm, say the goal is in a testing class and to make a mock of the class such that `type` checks like `type(MockFoo()) is Foo` might pass.

Comment: @flakes you can do it on a per-instance basis trivially, by `instance.__class__ = Foo`, and probably using some metaclass black magic you could do it in `MockFoo`, but it would be filled with landmines

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just tried that with `class Foo: pass` and `class Bar: pass` then `foo=Foo();foo.__class__ = Bar` but I get `TypeError: __class__ assignment only supported for heap types or ModuleType subclasses`

Comment: @flakes yeah, you'd have to do this in Python 3, or try inheriting from `object` in Python 2 (which you should always do anyways in Python 2 to use "new" style classes)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are you sure? FWIW I am on python 3.7.2 https://gist.github.com/cal-pratt/309ec0a5a05731e69aeda465b4e8448f

Comment: @flakes you meant `foo = Foo()`, not `foo = Foo`. you simply aliased the class object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh you are right, but this does now have the side effect of causing `test` for the foo instance to redirect to `Bar` (updated it in the gist). I'm going to post a new question for the black magic metaclass approach this has peaked my curiosity! :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga posted here if you're interested on weighing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879245/is-it-possible-to-make-the-output-of-type-return-a-different-class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to fundamentally misunderstand what `type` does. `type` itself is just a class, a *metaclass*. When you call `type` on an instance, it returns the class object that corresponds to that instance, pretty much equivalent to `instance.__class__`. However, you simply want to change the way the class object is *represented when you print it*, so you'd need to implement a metaclass for `MyMathOBJ` that overrides `__repr__` in the metaclass to accomplish this.

Here is how you accomplish what you are actually trying to do:

```
In [12]: class PrettyType(type):
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return self.__name__
    ...:

In [13]: class MyMathOBJ(metaclass=PrettyType):
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [14]: obj = MyMathOBJ()

In [15]: obj
Out[15]: <MyMathOBJ at 0x1060cbcc0>

In [16]: type(obj)
Out[16]: MyMathOBJ
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `x.__class__` but that does *not* change `type(x)`

Comment: The parameter name in `__repr__` should be called `cls` rather than `self`, since it's in a metaclass and the instances are classes.

Comment: Maybe this could be improved by adding a short paragraph explicitly stating there is no `__type__` special method in the language, with a link to the datamodel where most special dunder methods are described.