# Is it possible to make the output of `type` return a different class?

Tags: python, types, metaclass

So disclaimer: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879033/how-do-i-override-type-method-in-python-object?noredirect=1#comment100306740_56879033) has piqued my curiosity a bit, and I'm asking this for purely educational purposes. More of a challenge for the Python gurus here I suppose!

Is it possible to make the output of `type(foo)` return a different value than the actual instance class? i.e. can it pose as an imposter and pass a check such as `type(Foo()) is Bar`?

[@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) made a suggestion of manually re-assigning `__class__` on the instance, but that has the effect of changing how all other methods would be called. e.g.

```
class Foo:
    def test(self):
        return 1

class Bar:
    def test(self):
        return 2


foo = Foo()
foo.__class__ = Bar
print(type(foo) is Bar)
print(foo.test())

>>> True
>>> 2
```

The desired outputs would be `True`, `1`. i.e The class returned in `type` is different than the instance, and the instance methods defined in the real class still get invoked.

Comment: Do you just want to do this for a specific instance `foo`, or for the entire `Foo` class?

Comment: The more I think about this, the less feasible I see it. You could probably mock using `isinstance` by creating a mock class using an abstract base class and `__subclasscheck__`. but using `type` and `is`.... not sure

Comment: @Barmar Could just be for an instance. I'm curious about if a specific instance can manipulate the result returned from `type`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga me too. Might start digging in to the actual implementation of the `type` method to prove if it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - the `__class__` attribute is a fundamental information on the layout of all Python objects as "seen" on the C API level itself. And that is what is checked by the call to `type`.

That means: every Python object have a slot in its in-memory layout with space for a single pointer, to the Python object that is that object's class.

Even if you use ctypes or other means to override protection to that slot and change it from Python code (since modifying `obj.__class__` with `=` is guarded at the C level), changing it effectively changes  the object type: the value in the `__class__` slot IS the object's class, and the `test` method would be picked from the class in there (Bar) in your example.

However there is more information here: in all documentation, `type(obj)` is regarded as equivalent as `obj.__class__` - however, if the objects'class defines a descriptor with the name `__class__`, it is used when one uses the form `obj.__class__`. `type(obj)` however will check the instance's `__class__` slot directly and return the true class.

So, this can "lie" to code using `obj.__class__`, but not `type(obj)`:

```
class Bar:
    def test(self):
        return 2

class Foo:
    def test(self):
        return 1
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return Bar
```

## Property on the metaclass

Trying to mess with creating a  `__class__` descriptor on the metaclass of `Foo` itself will be messy -- both `type(Foo())` and `repr(Foo())` will report an *instance* of `Bar`, but the "real" object class will be Foo. In a sense, yes, it makes `type(Foo())` lie, but not in the way you were thinking about - type(Foo()) will output the repr of `Bar()`, but it is `Foo`'s repr that is messed up, due to implementation details inside `type.__call__`:

```
In [73]: class M(type): 
    ...:     @property 
    ...:     def __class__(cls): 
    ...:         return Bar 
    ...:                                                                                                                                               

In [74]: class Foo(metaclass=M): 
    ...:     def test(self): 
    ...:         return 1 
    ...:                                                                                                                                               

In [75]: type(Foo())                                                                                                                                   
Out[75]: <__main__.Bar at 0x55665b000578>

In [76]: type(Foo()) is Bar                                                                                                                            
Out[76]: False

In [77]: type(Foo()) is Foo                                                                                                                            
Out[77]: True

In [78]: Foo                                                                                                                                           
Out[78]: <__main__.Bar at 0x55665b000578>

In [79]: Foo().test()                                                                                                                                  
Out[79]: 1

In [80]: Bar().test()                                                                                                                                  
Out[80]: 2

In [81]: type(Foo())().test()                                                                                                                          
Out[81]: 1
```

## Modifying `type` itself

Since no one "imports" `type` from anywhere, and just use
the built-in type itself, it is possible to monkeypatch the builtin
`type` callable to report a false class - and it will work for all
Python code in the same process relying on the call to `type`:

```
original_type = __builtins__["type"] if isinstance("__builtins__", dict) else __builtins__.type

def type(obj_or_name, bases=None, attrs=None, **kwargs): 
    if bases is not None: 
        return original_type(obj_or_name, bases, attrs, **kwargs) 
    if hasattr(obj_or_name, "__fakeclass__"): 
        return getattr(obj_or_name, "__fakeclass__") 
    return original_type(obj_or_name) 

if isinstance(__builtins__, dict):
    __builtins__["type"] = type
else:
    __builtins__.type = type

del type
```

There is one trick here I had not find in the docs: when acessing `__builtins__` in a program, it works as a dictionary. However, in an interactive environment such as Python's Repl or Ipython, it is a 
module - retrieving the original `type` and writting the modified
version to `__builtins__`  have to take that into account - the code above
works both ways.

And testing this (I imported the snippet above from a .py file on disk):

```
>>> class Bar:
...     def test(self):
...          return 2
... 
>>> class Foo:
...    def test(self):
...         return 1
...    __fakeclass__ = Bar
... 
>>> type(Foo())
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> 
>>> Foo().__class__
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo().test()
1
```

Although this works for demonstration purposes, replacing the built-in type caused "dissonances" that proved fatal in a more complex environment such as IPython: Ipython will crash and terminate immediately if the snippet above is run.

Comment: That was really insightful! Thanks a lot for the post!